# MongoDB doesnt give the right result

Tags: json, mongodb

**Problem with mongoDB**

I have a collection in my mongodb with the following colums:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5443cddc425e215c7290a179"),  "orderid" : 1002854,  "customerid" : 45978,  "campaignid" : 2141,  "orderdate" : "2009-10-13 00:00:00",  "city" : "NEWTON",  "state" : "MA",  "zipcode" : 2459,  "paymenttype" : "VI",  "totalprice" : 190,  "numorderlines" : 3,  "numunits" : 3}
```

There are 239 different campaignid's, which all should have a value of 1, but they all have 0.

Now i want to have per campaignid the total amount of numunits grouped, which i use the following statement:

```
db.orders.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$campaignid", Numunits: {$sum:" $numunits"}}})
```

It gives back the following result:

```
{  "_id" : 2146,  "Numunits" : 0} , {  "_id" : 2111,  "Numunits" : 0} etc...
```

Now the expected result is:

```
{ "_id": 2146, "Numunits" : 93} , { "_id" : 2111, "Numunits" : 23} etc..
```

Comment: I think more information is required to either reproduce the problem or understand what you're expecting. How do you know that number is not correct?

Comment: Please give an example of your data, what result you expect from that data and what result you get instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo doesn't trim space for you if any. Try this:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
    [
       {$group: {
          _id: "$campaignid",
          Numunits: {$sum:"$numunits"}
          }
       }
    ])
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, is there any way i can select like the top 10 highest total sum from the collection based on this query?

Comment: db.orders.aggregate(
    [
       {$group: {
          _id: "$campaignid",
          Numunits: {$sum:"$numunits"}
          }
       },
       {$sort: {Numunits: -1},
       {$limit: 10}
    ])

Comment: What if i want to add extra colums? So like i want to group it by campaignid and productid?